# Uncaught TypeError when only accessing certain keys within array

Tags: php, curl

I am accessing an API using a cURL request in PHP. The response I receive contains the data I would expect, but when I loop through to process it, certain keys cause the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string." I've read through the numerous help questions here related to the error, but can't find anything with how to address a situation where "some" array keys cause an error.

**Edit #2**: I have determined that for some reason, the order of declaring the variables below is causing the error. If I simply move declaring `$transactionType` ***above*** `$transactionValue` with no other changes, the code works. Why would the order of accessing those values cause the code to fail? All data from the array is returned as strings from the API. (Leaving original statements unedited to give context and meaning to other answers)

My code:

```
$curl = curl_init($urlAPI);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'x-qn-api-version: 1',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
]);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);  
$decodedResponse = json_decode($response,true);
$transactionList = $decodedResponse["result"];
foreach($transactionList as $key => $value) {
  $timestamp = $value["timeStamp"];
  $hash = $value["hash"];
  $transactionValue = $value["value"];
  $transactionType = $value["functionName"];  //if I comment out this line with no other changes, it works as expected
  //Do stuff
}
```

As noted, if I comment out `$transactionType` it works perfectly and returns the 100+ results as expected. When I debug and `print_r($transactionList)`, the `functionName` key exists in every result (sometimes is empty, though). Another item of interest is if I use `isset` to check the `functionName` key first, it cannot find any instances where it is set - even though print_r clearly shows it is. An example of the result from the API:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( 
  [timeStamp] => 1624666351 
  [hash] => 0x37f2ec62dbd3f812215ae2e82dcfb11feb56d27255ab10ee102d4ce29942a347
  [transactionIndex] => 95 
  [value] => 132506677002809378 
  [functionName] => )
 [1] => Array ( 
  [timeStamp] => 1624672333 
  [hash] => 0x9eebfa157829c632b58f743bbe7fb018add5de7a3881796cc6764e942cccf458
  [transactionIndex] => 133 
  [value] => 122506677002809378 
  [functionName] => swap(uint256 amountOutMin, address[] path, address to, uint256 deadline) )
```

Where am I going wrong with this where my code breaks if I try to access `functionName`?

Comment: What  version of PHP are you using?  I highly doubt you would have gotten that error on version 5.6.   You know, I could help if I had an actual URL.  If I cannot test, I cannot help.

Comment: @Misunderstood, I am running on v8.1.11

Comment: Edited to add that if I use isset to check the functionName key first, it cannot find any instances where it is set - even though print_r clearly shows it is set

Comment: Now do you understand why I made that comment.  This problem would not exist if you were using 5.6 because strict typing was not introduced until version 7.  I cannot believe no one had told you yet.

Answer (score 1):

```php
// This might helps.
<?php
foreach($transactionList as $key => $value) {
      $timestamp = $value["timeStamp"];
      $hash = $value["hash"];
      $transactionValue = $value["value"];
      //trying isset
       if(isset($value["functionName"])){
          //validate data
          $transactionType = $value["functionName"];
          //Do stuff
       }else{
       //debug the data
       }
      
    }
?>
```

Comment: So this gets me away from the error, however, the conditional evaluates to "FALSE" and goes to the else clause even when the variable is set

Comment: If it's possible share json template so  we can able to debug

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

If you do not have complete control of all the code you may need to roll back from version 8.1. There is the same problem in a WordPress plugin so their only option was to roll back to 8.0.

> The entire error is "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot
> access offset of type string on string in xxxx/index.php:47 Stack
> trace: #0 {main} thrown in xxxx/index.php on line 47" The error is in
> the error_log file generated post-error; the page displays nothing.
> Line 47 correlates to the $transactionType variable's line. – 
> redstang423

That is a completely different error than originally anticipated.  The missing piece of the puzzle.

My best guess is this is the problem in the `swap()` function returned by the API:

```
[functionName] => swap(uint256 amountOutMin, address[] path, address to, uint256 deadline) )`
```

I do not know what swap returns, but that may be the source of the type error.

**END OF UPDATE**

---

▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬

---

It's a type declaration issue.

Type declarations can be added to **function arguments**, **return values**, and, as of PHP 7.4.0, **class properties**. They ensure that the value is of the specified type at call time, otherwise a TypeError is thrown.

[PHP Type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php)

Your variable type must match the type declared in the function.
You can change the type by using `intval(), strval(), boolval(), etc.`

If you need pass `$transactionType` to a function or class as an integer, then you need to set the type:

```
$transactionType = intval($value["functionName"]);
```

Or if it needs to be a string value:

```
$transactionType = strval($value["functionName"]);
```

If necessary in your trouble shooting, you can use `gettype()` which returns the type.

Comment: So, while this led me to the solution, I'm not certain it's the root cause, and now I'm even more confused. If I move the `$transactionType` variable ABOVE `$value` variable, even without using `strval` the code works - but, if it is below `$value`, it does not work, even when using `strval`. All data is returned as a string using `gettype()`. So for now my code is working, but I don't understand why changing the order of declaring the variables would break the code.

Comment: Where is the "Uncaught Type" error coming from?  That looks like a JavaScript error.  PHP errors tell you which line number.  Nothing is making sense here.  When that happens, it means to me a piece of the puzzle is missing.  In other words you are leaving out as critical explanation.  Moving  the position of those two lines means nothing.  There is something else going on here that you have not mentioned.  And if it was working, why did you change them? Why not leave them where it works?

Comment: I agree it makes no sense. I've left the page functional for now, but I want to understand why. The entire error is "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in xxxx/index.php:47 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in xxxx/index.php on line 47"
The error is in the error_log file generated post-error; the page displays nothing. Line 47 correlates to the $transactionType variable's line when it is placed after the $transactionValue variable. There's no javascript running on this page, and I only omitted API key/address and the HTML output from the code.

Comment: I guess you are using Uiniswap?  I am fairly confident the error is coming from the `swap()`.  That seems to be the only way you could get that error from that line of you PHP script.  Someone else with the same error got rid of the error by going back to PHP 8.0.

Comment: It's the Etherscan API. I'll have to see whether downgrading my PHP version fixes this. If not, you're likely right that it's something hidden within the API response